# What is the securitypack.jar in Java?

Tags: java, security, applet

I want to know what is the `securitypack.jar` in Java installation? What is it for?

I found that Java downloads this file automatically from: `https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/securitypack.jar` and saves inside:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\securitypack.jar

FIY: I'm using Windows 7 and latest Java 8 (u144). And in my case, this file was updated during Java Applet execution (or maybe initialization).

Comment: Almost certainly none of your business, but if you must know you could always run `jar tvf` on it and find out for yourself.

Comment: Why downvote? And why "none of your business"? @EJP look at P.J.Meisch answer. Moreover this mechanism could make a problem when there isn't Internet connection as described [here on StackExchange](https://superuser.com/questions/1105928/running-java-applet-in-ie-will-download-securitypack-jar). This is why some Java programmer should care about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's part of Oracle's [blacklist jar feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/blacklistfeature.html). The information about blacklisted jars and certificates is automatically updated by downloading securitypack.jar file